# What do the "wires" of "Set the wires of astronomical exchange" refer to?

Tags: meaning

The following sentence is taken from [*The War of the Worlds*](http://www.planetpdf.com/planetpdf/pdfs/free_ebooks/The_War_of_the_Worlds_NT.pdf) by H. G. Wells.
I do not understand what the phrase "set the wires of the astronomical exchange" means.  Does the word "wires" mean "messages by wire"?

> As Mars approached opposition, Lavelle of Java set **the wires of the 
>   astronomical exchange** palpitating with the amazing intelligence of a
>   huge  outbreak of incandescent gas upon the planet.

Comment: It may refer to *telegraph wires* or *telephone wires*. My guess would be the former but not having read the book, I cannot say.

Comment: The telephone was a new and innovative invention back in the mid 1890's when War of the Worlds was written.  It's highly probably that this is what Wells was referring to.  He probably had visions of frantic telephone calls between observatories and universities.

Comment: It's a long time since I read The War of the Worlds but it always seemed to me that Wells set it in what was, to him, the near future rather than the present. In Wells' near future the telephone would have become more widespread and more sophisticated than it was in his own time.

Comment: If you google "the wires humming" (the more usual ing-form nowadays) you will find examples.

Comment: @BoldBen According to [this article from the Pacific Telephone and Telegraph Co.](http://www.sfmuseum.org/hist7/pt&t.html) (courtesy the Virtual Museum of the City of San Francisco), there were over 11 000 telephones in use in San Francisco alone in 1897 (the year WotW was first published).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - However, it was some time later before (true) long-distance telephone use was practical.  The maximum long-distance call in 1892 was New York to Chicago.  Transcontinental calls were not possible until 1914 (and even then could take 10-20 minutes to set up).  [History of long-distance calling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-distance_calling#History)

Comment: @Hot Licks I find it difficult to get Mars even now.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - The point is that "the wires of the astronomical exchange" would span nations and possibly continents.  Telephone was basically a local thing in 1897.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspect, this refers to the [Telegraph](http://inventors.about.com/od/tstartinventions/a/telegraph.htm) wires.

Telegraphy had been in common use for decades before Wells' time and would be the most common form of communication between establishments such as astronomical observatories.

Use of phraseology regarding activity of the wires was also common in books and articles of the time.

Although the telephone did exist in the time of H.G.Wells, it was not yet the prevalent form of communication.

Comment: And I don't believe that "wires" was commonly used to refer to telephone communication, whereas the term was virtually synonymous with telegraph.

Comment: I'm not sure that telegraph messages were routed through exchanges.I thought that they were retransmitted to get them to places to which the originating node was not connected..